# Node JS res.redirect() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to redirect to some external url using res.redirect(), but the host name is not getting replaced.

Like
My current url: https://example.com

Wants to redirect to: https://example-2.com/pqr?par=123

on using res.redirect("https://example-2.com/pqr?par=123"), I am getting redirected to https://example.com/pqr?par=123

Comment: `res.redirect(301,"https://example-2.com/pqr?par=123")` should work

Comment: I tried everything, both with-without status code. But nothing is working. I am able to redirect in my local system by as soon as I push the code to server its not working
Below is the code



try {
        const authCodeUrlResponse = await msalInstance.getAuthCodeUrl(req.session.authCodeUrlRequest);
        console.log("authCodeUrlResponse.... ", authCodeUrlResponse);
        return res.redirect(301, authCodeUrlResponse);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }

authCodeUrlResponse is responding with complete urls with https://

Answer (score 0):

please share your complete code which you try redirect process. sometimes it will be a typo error but you can't see it :) and try to use redirect request with return;

```
return res.redirect("https://example-2.com/pqr?par=123");
```